# ios: why it call deinit immediately

Tags: ios, swift

today I faced a problem , the vc never call deinit, so I added a weak

```
func showAddCityViewController() {
        weak var vc:SWAddCityViewController!
        vc =  SWAddCityViewController()
        vc.delegate = self
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.presentVC(nav)
        })
    }
```

I run this function and then get a

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

the vc just go to nil ,but I don't know why , what should I do to make this code happy?

Comment: If you make the variable `weak` then the object will not be retained. Why do you do that? What's wrong with a plain `let vc = SWAddCityViewController()` ?

Comment: @Thilo sorry I am a newbie, the vc just don't call deinit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote this:

```
    weak var vc:SWAddCityViewController!
    vc =  SWAddCityViewController()
```

The `vc` variable is an “implicitly unwrapped Optional”, which means it can either point to an existing (not-deallocated) object, or it can be nil.

You create a new `SWAddCityViewController` object and assign it to `vc`. After the assignment statement completes, there is exactly one weak reference to the new object (in `vc`) and there are no strong references to it. An object is deallocated as soon as it has no strong references, so it is deallocated as soon as the assignment statement completes.

Since `vc` was a weak reference to the object, part of deallocating the object sets `vc` to nil. When you try to set `vc.delegate` on the next line, Swift generates code to unwrap `vc` automatically (since you declared it with `!`). Since `vc` is nil, you get a fatal error. You cannot unwrap an optional that's set to nil because it's not wrapping anything.

I don't see any reason to declare `vc` weak in that function. Just get rid of the `weak` attribute.

Your other complaint is that (with `weak`) the object doesn't get deallocated later. You have a “retain cycle”. Did you declare the `delegate` property of `SWAddCityViewController` using `weak`? You usually want to declare `delegate` properties `weak`.

If that doesn't fix the problem, you need to look for other places where you have a retain cycle involving the object.

Comment: thanks, the problem is the vc just don't call deinit when it dismissed, I don't know why, there is no closure in SWAddCityViewController at all

Comment: I think it may be a retain cycle

Comment: thank you for this long long anwser, yes it should be a retain cycle in SWAddCityViewController, but I can't find it , I use weak delegate but it does not  work

Comment: ohha, solved, it is the delegate that make it unhappy, I use a custom tableviewcell in SWAddCityViewController, and make SWAddCityViewController the delegate of the custom tableviewcell , it is not   weak , now SWAddCityViewController calls deinit. really thanks.